# Is it safe to use callbacks in socket.io events?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

While building my application with Node.js and Socket.io, I've been using callbacks to send data back to clients who make requests to the server.

During testing, I mistakenly sent a request from the client which did not include a callback. This triggered a warning message on the server:

```
(node:67072) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: callback is not a function
    at Socket.socket.on (server.js:247:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:127:13)
    at node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:527:12
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:150:11)
(node:67072) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 8)
(node:67072) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

What got my attention is the last `DeprecationWarning` about unhandled promise rejections terminating the Node.js process in the future. If this occurs, it seems it would be trivial to crash any Node.js program which uses Socket.io callbacks by simply emitting on a vulnerable event without a callback.

To my understanding, the only way to prevent this is to ensure the callback is defined before you ever use it:

```
socket.on('event', (params, callback) => {
    if (typeof callback !== 'function') { return null }

    /* do stuff */

    return callback(response)
}
```

Or, avoid using callbacks completely and only send data back to clients by `emit`-ing data to events they'll be listening for.

Is my understanding of this correct, or am I completely off-base here?

Comment: yes..you are correct...I think the same :) you should always handle the callbacks...

Comment: Yes, But isn't handling errors for code blocks one of the most important best practices in coding. Just that nodejs has made it come to your notice.

Comment: @damitj07 yes.. people often forget to do it... :P